# C++ Profiling on mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, profiling, profiler

I'm writing STL-only C++ application on mac(OS X Lion / XCode 4.1). I need to answer a simple question: which parts of code must be optimized? Gprof does empty output, XCode's Instruments doesn't help. Which tool I need to use?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty output"?  I think maybe your question should be "How do I get gprof to work?"

Comment: Looks like http://pastebin.com/EUhfSmLa

Comment: Instruments works very well for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Shark. It's in `/Developer/Applications/Performance Tools`

Very easy to use. More here: http://developer.apple.com/tools/sharkoptimize.html

Comment: This solution is obsolete, unfortunately. Shark has been replaced with Instruments (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8349036/130427). Instruments does not appear to be able to reference specific function calls the way Shark could.

Answer (score 0):

Even if *gprof* were working, [it would probably not be much help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343).

The method I rely on, for any language and OS, is [random pausing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

Here's how it works.
If you take several random-time samples of the stack, wasteful function calls or I/O appear in proportion to the fraction of time they waste. It has the advantage that problematic *statements* are pinpointed, as opposed to making you hunt within costly *routines*.