# is there a replacement for Shark in xcode 4?

Tags: java, xcode, macos

I recently installed Xcode 4. Unfortunately, I can't find the shark profiler, which was very convenient for profiling java applications. Did apple remove it? (and if so, why?) is there some replacement for it in Xcode 4?

(I actually read in another forum that I am not the first one to have this problem, and people who actually installed xcode4 could not find Shark either.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple now includes the [Java VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) with their developer tools for profiling Java applications. You can find it in `/Developer/Applications/Utilities` or `/usr/share/java/Tools`.

Answer (score 3):

Instruments is intended as a replacement for Shark. Most of the same functionality is in there, it's just moved around.

Sadly, my favorite Shark feature (ASM hints) appears to be gone in Instruments. :(

Comment: how do you use Instruments to time profile a java applications, if I may ask? generic time profiling does not give the java function names.

Comment: Use a Java-specific profiler -- neither Shark nor Instruments really know much about the internals of the JVM. There's a question about those at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/please-recommend-a-java-profiler

Comment: Shark does an excellent job peeking into the internals of the JVM and profiling which Java methods are running. I was hoping that Instruments could do the same.